error while refreshing my page after deploying my react-nest
1
Hi i am getting this error reactjs & nestjs application error while refreshing getting this error application
{"message":"Cannot GET /(for all my route only login page work while refreshing it) ","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404}

knowing that im deployin it using nginx and the configuration file look like this one below :
listen 8090;    
server_name localhost;      
location / {        
root C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cc-app\cc-front;        
index index.html;        
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;    
}      
location /api/ {        
rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;        
proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;        
proxy_read_timeout 9000s;                
}        
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;    
location = /50x.html {        
root   html;    
}}

ps : the problem does not occure while running application on localhost
